# how to make jQuery .load() to append returned data inside the container instead of rewrite on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I am using [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load html content from a controller action and put in an existing container element, The problem is that this coming data from the load method remove everything in this container and then write the new data there, What I want is to keep any content inside this container and just append the coming data.

here is my load:

```
$("#container").load("/Profile/Chat", { friendId: friendId });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.get("/Profile/Chat", { friendId: friendId }, function(html){
    $("#container").append(html);
}, 'html');
```

Answer (score 1):

`load` always replaces the content of the container. You can get around this by loading the content into a different hidden container, then `append` it to the intended container:

```
$("#hiddenContainer").load("/Profile/Chat", { friendId: friendId }, function() {
      $("#container").append($("#hiddenContainer").html());
});
```

Comment: ...or you can turn it into a `get` request and everything works like a charm with a single request.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but as the question asked for a way to do it with `load`, I thought I'd show a way of doing it. However, your method is undoubtedly better.

Comment: as a work around for using .load, this is very good, but in my case I am flexible and can use .get.

Comment: In most cases, `get` will be the best solution to this problem. But as I mentioned previously, I just thought I'd give a solution for `load`.

Answer (score 1):

`load`, `get`, `post` etc are all just wrappers around the jQuery `ajax` method. When in doubt, `ajax` always gets you what you want.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Profile/Chat",
    data: { friendId: friendId },
    success: function(data){
        $("#container").append(data);
    }
});
```